# my php code in form doesn't execute

Tags: php

when i'm trying to run my code i come across a blank site and i don't know how to fix it

i guess my calculations aren't working

here's the codes:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Kalkulator spalania paliwa</title>
</head>
<body align="center">
    <h1>Kalkulator spalania paliwa.</h1><br>
    <form action="get_info.php" method="get">
        Podaj spalone paliwo: <input type="text" name="sp"> l<br>
        Podaj przejechaną odległość: <input type="text" name="km"> km<br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

and

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php
    function spalanie(){
        $sp = $_GET["sp"];
        $km = $_GET["km"];
        $wynik = $sp * 100 / $km;
        echo $wynik;
    }
    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: In your second piece of code, you define a function to do the calculation, but never call it.  You need to call this function to get some output.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please have a look at the [ask] page and clarify your question: which page is blank, do you get any errors in your webserver's logs? (Checking the logs when having trouble with PHP is always helpful.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined the function but haven't called it. Call it like this below the function like

> spalanie();

Comment: Thanks, working now :)

Answer (score 0):

beacause your input tag has no value...

```
<input type="text" name="km" value="km">
```